# How can I generate a bitmap object at different location on the screen?

Tags: java, android, canvas, ondraw

How can i generate different apples at different locations on the screen, I implemented the below method to create an apple at the middle of the screen using `canvas.getWidth()/2` the changingY is a field of type float that stores the Y axis the apples fall from the top of the screen when an apple reach the bottom it starts again, so how can I generate different apples at different locations of the screen.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvass = (canvas.getWidth()/2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(apple, (canvas.getWidth()/2),chaningY, null); 
    if(chaningY < canvas.getHeight() ) {
        chaningY +=10;

    }else
    {
        chaningY = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: " how can I generate different apples at different locations of the screen. "

When do you want to generate these? On click on something, every second, or what? If you just want to generate another apple at that point of execution, just call canvas.drawBitmap again and change the x and y coordinates.

Comment: they should fall from the top at different location, I created a an apple basket to catch them. can I do it using the Random class

Comment: I want to generate them at different time like one second between each apple